# How can I write a shell-script that will email me a file if the file is not empty?

Tags: bash, email, shell

I'm looking for a script I can run to check if a text file is empty, if it is then do nothing but if it has something in it, I want it to send me an email with the text file as the message. No idea how to do it.

Comment: Platform? What will it be used for?

Comment: Also, The Title doesn't really say the question. It is more of a phrase. Try "Sending the Content of a Text File."

Comment: for linux sorry forgot to say that (although i did put the tags bash and shell-scripting)

I have a script that generated a list of changes and I want it to email me a copy every 30 minutes for backup purposes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[ -s "$f" ] && mail me@example.com -s "$f contents" < $f
```

Nice and compact :)

Answer (score 4):

For example:

```
test -s your_file && mutt -a your_file -s "Sending you a file" you@world.com
```

This will send the file as attachment. If you want to include the file in the message body, you can use the `-i` switch instead of the `-a`. If you don’t have Mutt installed you can call `mail`:

```
test -s your_file && mail -s "Sending you a file" you@world.com < your_file
```

Comment: copied it again, dunno what was wrong the first time... no errors but it doesn't send me anything :(

Answer (score 3):

As a script

```
#!/bin/bash
file=file_to_check
if [ -s ${file} ] ; then
  mail -s "The file is not empty!" me@foo.com < $file
fi
```

Or in one line. (To put in a crontab)

```
   [ -s file_to_check ] && mail -s 'File is not empty' me@foo.com < file_to_check
```

Comment: PERFECT!

I'll put it at the end of the script that generates the file so I wont need to estimate when the file will be there... just i just need it to send from a different email address lol but i'll read the man pages on mail and figure it out.

Comment: The '-z' test checks whether the string (file name) is zero length, not whether the file is zero length.

Comment: @Hintswen yep, it should be '-s' I should have manned test. That is what I get when I try to answer a question right before. Bed.

Comment: I prefer the multiline version due to legibility.  Not everything needs to be reduced to code golf.  Least of all shell scripting.  And Perl...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
if [ `wc -l file.txt` -gt 0 ]; then
    mail root@localhost < file.txt
fi
```

Comment: Interesting, but not very elegant compared with 'test -s' (usually spelled '[ -s ... ]').

Comment: However, if you change wc -l to wc -w, then the file will not be emailed if it just contains whitespace, which could be nice.

Comment: Yeah, I should have gone with `test -s`. It's been a while since I've written shell scripts.